# Question count should not be zero for ruby tag

Tags: bug, tags

I've seen this bug twice tonight, in two different tags: [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby) and [rspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rspec).  The current time is 2014-10-21T00:11:39-04

[image]

Comment: I'm getting 117,279 questions tagged ruby. Does it work after you hard refresh?

Comment: Yes.  It is not consistently reproducible.

Comment: Pretty sure I saw a different question a while ago with a similar thing for the featured tab count. Basically it runs a query, but the query does not finish in time. The page gets cached with a 0-counter and the next time the internal cache refreshes, the query has indeed completed and the correct number is shown.